# SVN: can't sense files when changed through shell script

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I apply simple script to change word in some files with another word.

```
for x in $(find .|grep Makefile) ;
do 
sed -i -e 's/certainWord/anotherword/g' $x ;
done
```

the changes occur in the file when I check it manually but when I try to commit svn files it doesn't sense that anyone has changed !

is it a known problem ?

I'm using smart svn tool to commit

Comment: Show us `svn status -v` after running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem.
the above script goes through the .svn directories and change the files in it in addition to the files in the working copy. that's why it didn't sense the change. as it seems it compares the working copy with the one under .svn {I'm new to svn :*}

my solution to that is to ignore the hidden folders to neglect .svn directory

```
for x in $(find . -not -path '*/\.*'|grep Makefile) ;
do 
sed -i -e 's/certainWord/anotherword/g' $x ;
done
```

Comment: For a possible speed improvement, consider using the following find command: `$(find . -name .svn -prune -o -name Makefile -print)`. This command won't waste time searching for files under the ".svn" directory.